# How to call a tsx function in a js file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, tsx

I am using react-meteor frame work. I want to reload room.tsx file when I click save on my js file.I have a tsx file as follows,

room.tsx,

```
const RoomList = (): ReactElement => {  
    usePreventDefault(ref);
    useShortcutOpenMenu(ref);
    useSidebarPaletteColor();

    return (
        <Box h='full' w='full' ref={ref}>
            <Virtuoso
                totalCount={roomsList.length}
                data={roomsList}
                components={{ Scroller: ScrollerWithCustomProps }}
                computeItemKey={computeItemKey}
                itemContent={(_, data): ReactElement => <RoomListRow data={itemData} item={data} />}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
```

edit.js

```
import { RoomList } '../../room';

function saveData() {
    await saveRoom({
        guestData,
        roomData,
    });
    setTimeout(()=>{
        RoomList();
    },4000)
}
```

WHEN I run the script I am getting RoomList is not a function. I am new to react can any one please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You need to export your `RoomList` function

Comment: You need to make a request in `RoomList`, place fetched data even in state and provide `state` as props to a child component that renders fetched data. You don't need to reload any component manually, `state` change will cause component re-render.